# Javascript regex remove new line inside double quote and double quote itself

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem with regex in javascript. for example i have recorver list of programming language to my csv file. what i want is i must replace all the programming that have newline inside the double quote, and also the double quote with a space the sample output below. the output must be Ruby on Rails and C++ without double quote and newline.

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

PYTHON

PHP

"Ruby on

Rails"

"C+

+"

**I TRIED THIS CODE**

how will i include also the new line inside the double quote

```
str.replace(/['"]+/g, ' ');
```

Comment: _the output must be Ruby on Rails and C++_ what does this mean?

Comment: You can't do it with a simple replacement string, you have to use a function as second parameter. Note that you also need to take in account if the newline is preceded and followed by a word boundary or not to choose between a space and an empty string.

Comment: `str.replace(/"[^"]+"/g, function(x) {return x.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, ' ')});`

Comment: And where's your input string?

Comment: Sample output is useless without sample input

Comment: He has sample input and output now. His point about *the output must be Ruby on Rails and C++* means he needs the new line removing and make it one line.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty with this question is that you have to find a way to know if the newline sequence must be replaced with a space or an empty string.
When the newline sequence is between word-boundaries, this means that there are a word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` before and after it (like in `on\nRails`). In this case it seems logical to send a space.
In other cases like `C+\n+` or any other string that starts or ends with a newline, you can return an empty string.

```
txt = txt.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, function (m,g) {
    return g.replace(/\b([\r\n]+)\b|[\r\n]+/g, function(n,h) {
        return h ? ' ' : '';
    });
});
```

Let me know if you find other (interesting) edge cases.

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly for my end. I don't understand why not have more upvotes